# PHP split street and housenumber

Tags: php, regex, string, split

so i need to split the streetname and housenumber, so if this is the string:

'Sample street 12'

and i want the street and number apart from eachother:

'Sample street' '12'

But also if there is a letter in the housenumber, like 1A it needs to come out as:

'Sample street' '1A'

I tried to use:

```
$straat = $order->get_shipping_address_1();
$straat = preg_replace("/[^A-Z]+/", "", $straat);
```

For the street,

And:

```
$str = $order->get_shipping_address_1();
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
```

For the number, but it returns just 1 character, or if the house number has a letter in it, it skips it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner What do you mean? im sorry, i did try a lot already it just doesn't work for me.

Comment: If you posted what you tried, at least it will give us something to go on and check if errors were made. We don't know what the data source is also.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Allright i will update it with that info, i dont think it will be helpful tho, like i said it wasn't what i was looking for.

Comment: Someone gave an answer below, did you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pattern which matches anything until a number followed by any number of characters(`\d\w*`).  It also uses word boundaries to split out the distinct number part...

```
$straat = 'Sample street 1A';
preg_match_all('!(.*)\b(\d\w*)\b!', $straat, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sample street 1A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sample street 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1A
        )

)
```